# Android:Передача данных между приложенииями , при отсутствии sdcard

Tags: android, java, файлы

Куда лучше всего сохранить файл на внутреннем хранилище с одного приложения , чтобы потом его открыть другим приложением, если отсутствует `sdcard`.

Или может подскажите другое решение...

Проблема лишь в том , что приложение от которого мне нужны данные, может только сохранять эти данные в определённые места. По другому от него данных не получить. (Долго объяснять ), но нужен рабочий способ...

Забыл добавить, девайс НЕ рутованый

Comment: Нет Android телефонов, у которых нет sd карты -_-

Comment: @Suvitruf есть такие :)

Comment: @Suvitruf покажете мне, где SD-карта в Sony Ericsson ST15i ?

Comment: @metalurgus если нет физической sd-карты - это ещё не значит, что нету виртуальной.

Answer (score 1):

[ContentProvider?](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)

[Пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/166-urok-101-sozdaem-svoj-contentprovider)